# Getting an unwanted space between Nav Items in Navbar Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to create a sidenav bar with nav items in it which has sub menus . I am able to create it but i am getting space between 2 navitems which have submenus .

I am trying that both these Admin and Support come one after the other and get slided down when sub menu is clicked .

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a var for admin and support length and make a loop like this

```html
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
  });
}
```